# ArrayList creation with Java 8 Lambda

Tags: java, python, arraylist, lambda

I would like to find a one-liner expression in Java that allows to instantiate an `ArrayList` and to insert some specific elements inside it.

For example, an expression that creates an `ArrayList` containing the numbers in the interval `[0, n]` divisible by 3.

I manage to insert the filtered elements into the `ArrayList`, but only using the `forEach` expression in the following way:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>;
IntStream.range(0, n + 1)
         .filter(number -> number % 3 == 0)
         .forEach(number -> numberList.add(number));
```

As you can see, it's necessary to separately instantiate the `ArrayList` and then insert the elements.

In Python, we can use the following one-liner:

```
numberList = [number for number in range(0, n + 1) if number % 3 == 0]
```

Is there something equivalent or similar to the code below in Java 8?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about collecting to a `List`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a collector to add the elements in a list :

```
int n = 10;
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, n + 1)
      .filter(number -> number % 3 == 0)
      .boxed() // converts IntStream to Stream<Integer> (primitive type to wrapper type)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit**: As Aominè said in the comments, you can also use `IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n)` instead of `IntStream.range(0, n + 1)`

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I tried to use the  `collect()` method without using `boxed()`  before. With `boxed()` everything works fine

Comment: @AlessandroBardini In this case you would have to do `.collect(ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll);` which would be the equivalent of `.boxed().collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Comment: Both should have the same performance. The former (with `boxed`) is neater.

Comment: more suitable to use `IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n)` rather than `IntStream.range(0, n + 1)` in this case.